# Loading UIViewController inside an UIScrollView Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have 2 `UIViewController`s.
One `UIViewController` has a view with many buttons and is +2000 points high.
Another `UIViewController` has a `UIScrollView`.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 2884)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let thumb_vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thumb") as! ThumbsViewController
        //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(thumb_vc)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(thumb_vc.view)
   }
 }
```

and although the thumbs `UIViewController` get loaded to `UIScrollView`, the size is wrong and does not scroll.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Use in your project autolayout or size class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into an issue with the Views being resized when loaded at run-time. Couple options...

```
// NOT USING constraints / auto-layout
func setupA() -> Void {

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 2884)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thumb") as? ThumbsViewController {

        // add the child VC
        self.addChildViewController(vc)

        // don't let "thumbs" view auto-resize
        vc.view.autoresizingMask = []

        // set "thumbs" view frame size to scroll view content size
        vc.view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: scrollView.contentSize)

        // add "thumbs" view to the scroll view
        self.scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)

        // finish child VC process
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

}

// USING constraints / auto-layout, with hard-coded sizing
func setupB() -> Void {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thumb") as? ThumbsViewController {

        // add the child VC
        self.addChildViewController(vc)

        // add "thumbs" view to the scroll view
        self.scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)

        // disable auto-resizing mask
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set constraints to both control the size of the "thumbs" view
        // as well as the contentSize of the scroll view

        // set width and height constraints for the "thumbs" view
        vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 375).isActive = true
        vc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2884).isActive = true

        // set leading, top, trailing, and bottom constraints to the scroll view
        vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        // finish child VC process
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

}

// USING constraints / auto-layout, with sizing controlled by constraints set in IB for the "thumbs" view
func setupC() -> Void {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "althumb") as? ALThumbsViewController {

        // add the child VC
        self.addChildViewController(vc)

        // add "thumbs" view to the scroll view
        self.scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)

        // disable auto-resizing mask
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // the constraints set in Interface Builder for the elements in the "thumbs" view
        // will control its size

        // setting the "edge" constraints relative to the scroll view will control the contentSize

        // set leading, top, trailing, and bottom constraints to the scroll view
        vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        // finish child VC process
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

}
```

I'd recommend the method in `setupC()` It uses auto-layout constraints with no hard-coded size values. Makes it much easier to plan for different device sizes (and future use in other views / apps / jobs / etc).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you giving static height to ScrollView when you can easily embed View in scroll view using Autolayout.
You can refer this link,
https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: You refer direct scrollview link not home page link https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Answer (score 0):

You must specify your child's frame too. Also there is no need to dispatch your UI changes to main queue in the `viewDidLoad` method. And you must call your child view controller's `didMove(toParentViewController:)` method after adding it's view as your subview. You can read more about container view controllers and their children [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/).